# Pass string from [NgStyle]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello i want to show a textarea when i press a button on the same page.

html

```
<button ion-button [NgStyle]="type=='text'">

   <ion-item *ngIf="type=='text'">
      <ion-textarea>....</ion-texarea>
   </ion-item>
```

.ts

```
type:string='';
 component(){}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `[NgStyle]` is used to give the component dynamic css. That's not what you are doing there. Also, you didn't give your button any eventlistener: `(click)="doSomething()"`

Comment: Thanks i used NgClass to filter results so i was confused. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

inside HTML:

```
<ion-button color="primary" (click)="showHidetextArea()"></ion-button

   <ion-item *ngIf="show">
      <ion-textarea></ion-texarea>
   </ion-item>
```

inside .ts

```
show: boolean = false; // declear variable

showHidetextArea(){
      this.show = !this.show;
}
```